# How to divide services and capacities in a graph?

Tags: graphs, distributed-systems, network-flow, algorithm-design

Given a graph where some nodes can provide some services with x,y,z... capacities. A node connected to multiple nodes needs to divide these services to the connected nodes and these nodes themselves should further divide this to their connected nodes. when a node receives two services from 2 differnt nodes it is connected to it merges them and then devide them to the other nodes it is connected to. The goal is to make this division as optimal as possible while maximizing the services each node has access to. How can I do this any hints? Or is this possibly similar to some famous problem? Also what happens if at each point I do not know the topology of the whole graph?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [flow networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network)?

Comment: @Juho  but in flow network, I know the capacity of each link however here I need to decide  on the capacity of each link